# In-place interleaving of the two halves of a string

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm, math

Given a string of *even* size, say:

```
abcdef123456
```

How would I interleave the two halves, such that the *same* string would become this:

```
a1b2c3d4e5f6
```

I tried attempting to develop an algorithm, but couldn't. Would anybody give me some *hints* as to how to proceed? I need to do this without creating extra string variables or arrays. One or two variable is fine.

I just don't want a working code (or algorithm), I need to develop an algorithm and prove it correctness mathematically.

Comment: This isn't an efficient solution, but it's a start. What about an algorithm  which solves the first two characters `a1`, fixes the array and then repeats with the smaller array. Obviously it isn't performant because getting `abcdef123456` to `a1bcdef23456` can't be efficient (unless the string is represented as linked list?). What requirements do you have on the runtime? Or are you just looking for a clever algorithm?

Comment: Is your string an array or a linked list?

Comment: It looks like it's some kind of self-similar building sequence the longer the two halves get. I have to go to church, but I have my notes here: http://pastebin.com/nBQf4q90 Mostly just observing how the moves you need to make change as the length changes. I think if you extend it a bit longer the relationship will become clearer.

Comment: @roliu: Yup. I've looking for *clever* (and efficient) algorithm whose correctness can be proved. Also, string is a string, say, `std::string` or `char[N]`, **not a linked-list**.

Comment: @Patashu: I didn't get your notes. It has no explanation as to why you swap characters at certain indices? How do you compute indices?

Comment: And you obviously want it better than O(length²) in terms of time, right?

Comment: @Nawaz my answer had been downvoted, but it seems to me it is the simplest so far. Here is the way it works: find the middle and iterate till the end(i variable for example). i-middle is going to the letter, i is going to be digit. Then concatenate them and so on.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Obviously, as O(n*n) would be an easy solution.

Comment: @Eugene: Your solution doesn't solve the problem I asked.

Comment: From the comments in a cstheory post: http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1598.

Comment: @tigger: I cannot see that.

Comment: @Nawaz, does this work http://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.1598v1.pdf. They solve a very slight variation of your problem (but it should be clear how to get from your problem to theirs and vice versa). This is simply swapping the first and second blocks, which should be clear as O(n).

Comment: @tigger Oh wow: "In [EM00] it has been shown that the problem of merging lists in-place can
be reduced to performing in-shuﬄes in-place". I don't think we can do this problem on SO then haha.

Comment: The reference @roliu is mentioning is exactly your problem: J. Ellis and M. Markov. In-situ, stable merging by way of perfect shuﬄe. The Computer Journal. 43(1):40-53, (2000)

Answer (score 6):

You may be able to do it in O(N*log(N)) time:

```
Want: abcdefgh12345678 -> a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8

a b c d e f g h
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

  4 1-sized swaps:

a 1 c 3 e 5 g 7
  b 2 d 4 f 6 h 8

a1  c3  e5  g7
    b2  d4  f6  h8

  2 2-sized swaps:

a1  b2  e5  f6
    c3  d4  g7  h8

a1b2  e5f6
      c3d4  g7h8

  1 4-sized swap:

a1b2  c3d4
      e5f6  g7h8

a1b2c3d4
        e5f6g7h8
```

Implementation in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(void* pa, void* pb, size_t sz)
{
  char *p1 = pa, *p2 = pb;
  while (sz--)
  {
    char tmp = *p1;
    *p1++ = *p2;
    *p2++ = tmp;
  }
}

void interleave(char* s, size_t len)
{
  size_t start, step, i, j;

  if (len <= 2)
    return;

  if (len & (len - 1))
    return; // only power of 2 lengths are supported

  for (start = 1, step = 2;
       step < len;
       start *= 2, step *= 2)
  {
    for (i = start, j = len / 2;
         i < len / 2;
         i += step, j += step)
    {
      swap(s + i,
           s + j,
           step / 2);
    }
  }
}

char testData[][64 + 1] =
{
  { "Aa" },
  { "ABab" },
  { "ABCDabcd" },
  { "ABCDEFGHabcdefgh" },
  { "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPabcdefghijklmnop" },
  { "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0<({[/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1>)}]\\" },
};

int main(void)
{
  unsigned i;

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(testData) / sizeof(testData[0]); i++)
  {
    printf("%s -> ", testData[i]);
    interleave(testData[i], strlen(testData[i]));
    printf("%s\n", testData[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/bYAvRi)):

```
Aa -> Aa
ABab -> AaBb
ABCDabcd -> AaBbCcDd
ABCDEFGHabcdefgh -> AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHh
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPabcdefghijklmnop -> AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPp
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0<({[/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1>)}]\ -> AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz01<>(){}[]/\
```

Comment: +1. Nice. very nice. Now, how to prove its correctness? Can it be further improved?

Comment: I don't understand why swapping multiple characters is considered to be an `O(1)` operation. Why wouldn't you just consider shifting an entire set of characters to be `O(1)` and then the linear solution is trivial? `abcd1234` => `a_bcd234` is `O(1)`? Not to belittle this solution because it's clever, but I don't think the runtime analysis makes much sense.

Comment: I think, induction should do the trick. A layman can just observe it work for the lengths of 4, 8, 16, 32 and 64 and stop there. I don't know if this can be improved further. I actually doubt that this particular approach can be significantly improved.

Comment: @roliu I do not consider swapping of groups of multiple characters as O(1). Look at the comments: `4 1-sized swaps`, ..., `1 4-sized swap`. Note that I do mention the size of the swap and the number of swaps at each level. Their product is constant and is *linear* in the `length` of the string. However, there are only `log2(length)` levels. That gives you `length*log2(length)` operations or time.

Comment: You're right. I'm too tired. I thought of another algorithm that uses swaps for the same runtime. Instead of working _outside_ towards the middle, it just sort of moves characters to where they should be: `abcdefgh12345678 => abcd 1234 efgh 5678 => ab 12 cd 34 ef 56 gh 78 => a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e 5 f 6 g 7 h 8`

Comment: @roliu Looks like you can do it in that direction as well.

Answer (score 3):

Generically that problem is quite hard -- and it reduces to finding *permutation cycles*. The number and length of those varies quite a lot depending on the length.

[image: Cycles for in-place interleaving for 10 and 12 entry arrays]

The first and last cycles are always degenerate; the 10 entry array has 2 cycles of lengths 6 and 2 and the 12 entry array has a single cycle of length 10.

Withing a cycle one does:

```
 for (i=j; next=get_next(i) != j; i=next) swap(i,next);
```

Even though the function next can be implemented as some relatively easy formula of N, the problem is postponed to do book accounting of what indices have been swapped. In the left case of 10 entries, one should [quickly] find the starting positions of the cycles (they are e.g. 1 and 3).

Answer (score 2):

Ok lets start over. Here is what we are going to do:

```
def interleave(string):
    i = (len(string)/2) - 1
    j = i+1

    while(i > 0):
        k = i
        while(k < j):
            tmp = string[k]
            string[k] = string[k+1]
            string[k+1] = tmp
            k+=2 #increment by 2 since were swapping every OTHER character
        i-=1 #move lower bound by one
        j+=1 #move upper bound by one
```

Here is an example of what the program is going to do. We are going to use variables `i`,`j`,`k`. `i` and `j` will be the lower and upper bounds respectively, where `k` is going to be the index at which we swap.

**Example**

```
`abcd1234`

i = 3 //got this from (length(string)/2) -1

j = 4 //this is really i+1 to begin with

k = 3 //k always starts off reset to whatever i is 

swap d and 1
increment k by 2 (k = 3 + 2 = 5), since k > j we stop swapping

result `abc1d234` after the first swap

i = 3 - 1 //decrement i
j = 4 + 1 //increment j
k= 2 //reset k to i

swap c and 1, increment k (k = 2 + 2 = 4), we can swap again since k < j
swap d and 2, increment k (k = 4 + 2 = 6), k > j so we stop
//notice at EACH SWAP, the swap is occurring at index `k` and `k+1`

result `ab1c2d34`

i = 2 - 1
j = 5 + 1
k = 1

swap b and 1, increment k (k = 1 + 2 = 3), k < j so continue
swap c and 2, increment k (k = 3 + 2 = 5), k < j so continue
swap d and 3, increment k (k = 5 + 2 = 7), k > j so were done

result `a1b2c3d4`
```

As for proving program correctness, see this [link](http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C455/html/notes/Chapter2/LoopInvariantProof.htm). It explains how to prove this is correct by means of a loop invariant.

A rough proof would be the following:

1. Initialization: Prior to the first iteration of the loop we can see that `i` is set to
   `(length(string)/2) - 1`. We can see that i <= length(string) before we enter the loop.
2. Maintenance. After each iteration, `i` is decremented (`i = i-1, i=i-2,...`) and there must be a point at which `i<length(string)`.
3. Termination: Since `i` is a decreasing sequence of positive integers, the loop invariant `i > 0` will eventually equate to false and the loop will exit.

Comment: Please read the question. It says "in-place" interleaving. With extra string variables, the problem is easy which I didn't ask.

Comment: my bad, thats also easy to do, let me fix it

Comment: Also, explain your solution.

Comment: gimme a sec, i didnt read the question correctly, fixing the issues

Comment: ok i fixed it, now i wrote this in python but it will not run, `string[0] = 'a'` is not supported but I kept it so you can understand it better.

Comment: Ah this answer is actually pretty cool. The runtime isn't linear though. I think there are a few solutions that are "cyclical" in nature that can achieve it in this `n^2` runtime. In particular, I was thinking of a solution where you first place the 2nd half into the correct locations (the odd indices) and then fix up the even indices (the hard part. But it's not actually that hard). It is also `n^2` though. *edit* I noticed above that you said `O(n^2)` was obviously too slow... I realize that the brute force solution is also `O(n^2)` heh. But a few solutions are "cleverer"

Comment: Yepp, its still O(n^2). If it was a linked list, it would have been O(n) by doing what you said, place the second half in the correct locations and fix up the pointers..

Comment: Ah my solution was actually something like this:
`abcd1234 => a1c2b3d4` after first step (brute force swap to get numbers in the right slots). Then fix the even index'd first half (the `a` and `c`). `a1c2b3d4` => `a1b2c3d4`. And then fix the odd index`d first half (the `b` and `d`). The logic for this last step is complicated but it pretty much is the cycle stuff mentioned above. Basically you start with the first index `1` and you say "where could the character at index 1 have gone in this entire process?" and you recompute the current index of it. When you've found it, you swap. Ugly :P

Comment: By the way, your rough proof only seems to prove that your algorithm terminates. It doesn't show proof of correctness.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is here J. Ellis and M. Markov. In-situ, stable merging by way of perfect shuﬄe.
The Computer Journal. 43(1):40-53, (2000).

Also see the various discussions here:

1. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/332/in-place-algorithm-for-interleaving-an-array/400#400
2. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/13943/linear-time-in-place-riffle-shuffle-algorithm.

Comment: " I need to do this without creating extra string variables or arrays"

Comment: It is **in-place** interleaving. So no extra memory/string/arrays. Also, recursion effectively uses extra memory (it is a just a clever way to create lots of variables which is not allowed.)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's a rough draft.  You say you don't just want an algorithm, but you are taking hints, so consider this algorithm a hint:

Length is N.

k = N/2 - 1.

1) Start in the middle, and shift (by successive swapping of neighboring pair elements) the element at position N/2 k places to the left (1st time: '1' goes to position 1).

2) --k.  Is k==0?  Quit.

3) Shift (by swapping) the element at N/2 (1st time:'f' goes to position N-1) k places to the right.

4) --k.

**Edit**: The above algorithm is correct, as the code below shows.  Actually proving that it's correct is waaay beyond my capabilities, fun little question though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(void)
{
    std::string s("abcdefghij1234567890");
    int N = s.size();
    int k = N/2 - 1;
    while (true)
    {

        for (int j=0; j<k; ++j)
        {
            int i = N/2 - j;
            std::swap(s[i], s[i-1]);
        }

        --k;

        if (k==0) break;

        for (int j=0; j<k; ++j)
        {
            int i = N/2 + j;
            std::swap(s[i], s[i+1]);
        }

        --k;
    }

   std::cout << s << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could just shift the elements in O(length²) operations or is that what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm and working code. It is in place, O(N), and conceptually simple.

1. Walk through the first half of the array, swapping items into place.

   - Items that started in the left half will be swapped to the right
     before we need them, so we use a trick to determine where they
     were swapped to.
2. When we get to the midpoint, unscramble the unplaced left items that were swapped to the right.

   - A variation of the same trick is used to find the correct order for unscrambling.
3. Repeat for the remaining half array.

This goes through the array making no more than N+N/2 swaps, and requires no temporary storage.

The trick is to find the index of the swapped items.  Left items are swapped into a swap space vacated by the Right items as they are placed.  The swap space grows by the following sequence:

- Add an item to the end(into the space vacated by a Right Item)
- Swap an item with the oldest existing (Left) item.

Adding items 1..N in order gives:
`1 2 23 43 435 465 4657 ...`
The index changed at each step is:
 `0 0  1 0   2  1      3 ...`

This sequence is exactly [OEIS A025480](https://oeis.org/A025480/list), and can be calculated in O(1) amortized time:

```
def next_index(n):
    while n&1: n=n>>1
    return n>>1
```

Once we get to the midpoint after swapping N items, we need to unscramble. The swap space will contain N/2 items where the actual index of the item that should be at offset `i` is given by `next_index(N/2+i)`. We can advance through the swaps space, putting items back in place. The only complication is that as we advance, we may eventually find a source index that is left of the target index, and therefore has already been swapped somewhere else. But we can find out where it is by doing the previous index look up again.

```
def unscramble(start,i):
        j = next_index(start+i)
        while j<i: j = next_index(start+j)
        return j
```

Note that this only an indexing calculation, not data movement.  In practice, the total number of calls to `next_index` is < 3N for all N.

That's all we need for the complete implementation:

```
def interleave(a, idx=0):
    if (len(a)<2): return
    midpt = len(a)//2 

    # the following line makes this an out-shuffle.
    # add a `not` to make an in-shuffle
    base = 1 if idx&1==0 else 0

    for i in range(base,midpt):
        j=next_index(i-base)
        swap(a,i,midpt+j)

    for i in range(larger_half(midpt)-1):
        j = unscramble( (midpt-base)//2, i);
        if (i!=j):
            swap(a, midpt+i, midpt+j)

    interleave(a[midpt:], idx+midpt)
```

The tail-recursion at the end can easily be replaced by a loop. It's just less elegant with Python's array syntax. Also note that for this recursive version, the input must be a numpy array instead of a python list, because standard list slicing creates copies of the indexes that are not propagated back up.

Here's a quick test to verify correctness. (8 perfect shuffles of a 52 card deck restore it to the original order).

```
A = numpy.arange(52)
B = A.copy()
C =numpy.empty(52)

for _ in range(8):
    #manual interleave
    C[0::2]=numpy.array(A[:26])
    C[1::2]=numpy.array(A[26:])
    #our interleave
    interleave(A)
    print(A)
    assert(numpy.array_equal(A,C))

assert(numpy.array_equal(A, B))
```

Comment: C implementation and another attempt at explanation [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/105263/58310).