# Merging two very large lists

Tags: algorithm, list, merge

Given a list of size 2n -1 elements and the list looks like this:

`x1, x2, x3, ....., xn, y1, y2, y3, ....y(n-`1)

Convert it to:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, ........., y(n-1), xn
```

I can use two iterators for each of the lists and get the solution in O(n) time complexity and O(n) space complexity. But if my n was very large, is there a way to do this in lesser space complexity?

Comment: you really have to explicitly merge the two lists? you could easily said what is the `k-th` element from the resulting list without really performing the merge.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338654/move-all-odd-positioned-element-to-left-half-and-even-positioned-to-right-half-i

Comment: @svs I do have to merge the lists and queue them up for some other program to use.

Comment: For the more general problem of efficiently applying an arbitrary permutation in place, see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6711/complexity-of-applying-a-permutation-in-place

Comment: @MBo I think that's the inverse of this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996288/in-place-interleaving-of-the-two-halves-of-a-string

Comment: Also: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/332/, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/13943

Comment: @MBo I don't think I can use the Cycle Leader Iteration Algorithm here.

Comment: @augurar Yes, but the same approach - transpose 2xN matrix inplace

Comment: @tanvi This is one specific method of transposition. Of course, you may use another.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like this can be done with O(1) space and O(n) time but the algorithm is far from trivial. Basically take an element that is out of place, say x2, look where it needs to be in the final arrangement take out the element that is there (i.e. x3) and put in x2.
Now look where x3 needs to go and so on.

When the cycle is closed, take the next element that is out of place (if there is any).

Lets do an example:

```
x1 x2 x3 y1 y2      x2 is out of place so take it into temp storage
x1 -- x3 y1 y2      temp: x2       needs to go where x3 currently is
x1 -- x2 y1 y2      temp: x3       needs to go where y2 currently is
x1 -- x2 y1 x3      temp: y2       needs to go where y1 currently is
x1 -- x2 y2 x3      temp: y1       needs to go into the empty slot
x1 y1 x2 y2 x3      all elements in place -> finished
```

If the array indices start at 0, the final position of the element at k is given by

```
2k            if k < n
2(k-n) + 1    if k >= n
```

The difficulty is to find out an element of a cycle that is not yet handled. For example if n = 4 there are 3 cycles:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1
3 -> 6 -> 5 -> 3
```

I do not have an easy solution for that at the moment.

If you have one bit of storage available per array element it is trivial but then we are back to O(n) storage.

Comment: I am not able to exactly picture this. Could you please explain using 3-4 elements?

Comment: That looks neat. But how do I make sure I did not lose any element? Also, what would be the complexity of finding where my element goes?

Comment: any thoughts for me to begin with?

Comment: How do you know "the next element that is out of place" after completing a cycle?

Comment: If you take an element, how do you know "where it needs to be in the final arrangement"?

Comment: @nwellnhof You can compute an element's final position from its initial position (see the second code block).

Comment: Nice explanation. @Henry +1

Comment: @psyco The missing part of this answer (finding the cycle leaders) is the crux of the whole algorithm, the rest is trivial.

Comment: @augurar Can you please provide me some test case where i can judge upon Henry's approach.

Answer (score -1):

In Python:

```
lst = 'x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5'.split()

lst
Out[9]: ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y5']

out = sum((list(xy) for xy in zip(lst[:len(lst)//2], lst[len(lst)//2:])), [])

out
Out[11]: ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3', 'x4', 'y4', 'x5', 'y5']
```

Comment: This takes `O(n)` additional space, which the OP explicitly wanted to avoid.